# Can I add a ppa to a custom sources.list?

Tags: ppa, software-sources

Is there any way to add a ppa to a specific sources.list?
`add-apt-repository` by default adds new ppa to `/etc/sources.list`, I want to add a ppa to `mysources.list`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add it to `mysources.list` so long as you put that file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

You can read more about how `apt` searches for sources with `man sources.list`.